# Does ZFS maintain local application crash-consistency with sync=disabled?

Tags: zfs

Documentation for the `sync=disabled` property states that

```
File system transactions are only committed to stable storage periodically.  This option will give the
highest performance.  However, it is very dangerous as ZFS would be ignoring the synchronous transac-
tion demands of applications such as databases or NFS.  Administrators should only use this option
when the risks are understood.
```

so I am trying to understand those risks. Unfortunately, there is some conflicting information regarding what exactly happens when `sync=disabled` and a crash/power loss occurs and what implications does it have for practical applications.

Here's a small sample of (paraphrased) comments on various forums, discussing `sync=disabled` safety:

- You can set `sync=disabled` if you don't care about losing the last 5 seconds of writes.
- There is no risk of corruption with `sync=disabled`, only data loss.
- ZFS stays crash-consistent even with `sync=disabled`.
- You will only be crash-consistent, from the filesystem level, not from the application level.
- By setting `sync=disabled`, you loose transaction safety for database applications.
- ACID compliant databases are atomic and ZFS preserves atomicity and ordering of writes even with `sync=disabled`.
- You are deliberately lying to the software. Even ACID databases and journalling filesystems (running on top of ZFS) may be broken, because you are violating the expected write semantics.

So which is it? Do I only lose 5 seconds of data (as if the crash just occurred 5 seconds earlier, but with `sync=standard`) or do these 5 seconds introduce some transactional uncertainty, that breaks consistency for ACID databases?

To be clear, I understand that I will lose the last 5 seconds of transactions. The question is can these 5 seconds of loss lead to application level corruption of state (assuming the application state is ZFS-local, so consistency with a remote server or a separate non-ZFS disk doesn't matter).

If `sync=disabled` **can** cause application level corruption of state, please provide a description or a sequence diagram, illustrating how can such a corruption occur.

Edit: Again, I want to make clear, that I don't care about Durability and I don't care about 5 seconds of data loss. My question is **only** about Consistency and transaction safety. There is a **huge** difference between loosing about 5 seconds of data (because of transaction rollbacks) and loosing Consistency (loosing all of your data if the corrupted data could not be repaired).

Comment: "so I am trying to understand those risks" : My opinion is that you cannot *understand* the impacts of this feature "per se". I mean irrespective of what precisely crashed and caused the crash (from the hardware failure of some component to kernel panic)

Answer (score 1):

> So which is it?

All of them about the same - data **not** flushed on a disk are lost.

> - There is no risk of corruption with `sync=disabled`, only data loss.

Data loss **also** means possibility of corruption or logical incosistency of stored data. It depends on **what** data is lost exactly.

> - ZFS stays crash-consistent even with `sync=disabled`.
> - You will only be crash-consistent, from the filesystem level, not from the application level.

'Consistency' here is about consistency of filesystem itself only (i.e. metadata) and not about **logical** consistency of application's data stored in filesystem.

> - By setting `sync=disabled`, you loose transaction safety for database applications.

Yes.

> - ACID compliant databases are atomic and ZFS preserves atomicity and ordering of writes even with `sync=disabled`

It's unclear for ordering.
Inside transaction group writes
can be reordered:
https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T17417b2984f6c8ff
Or not:
https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T969c74e0a6dfdd74-M818821038c9248d92443f67a

Atomicity provided by application itself. And [atomicity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) not equal [durability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(database_systems)).

> - You are deliberately lying to the software. Even ACID databases and journalling filesystems (running on top of ZFS) may be broken, because
>   you are violating the expected write semantics.

Yes.

> Do I only lose 5 seconds of data ...
> or do these 5 seconds introduce some transactional uncertainty, that breaks consistency for ACID databases?

Both. Both states the same thing - you lost {application's) data.

It's all about write caching on all layers between app and physical media.
If **any** data from **any** (non-persistent) cache not flushed to the media they lost.

With sync disabled filesystem not flush cached data **immediately** when app force it to do but lies that the data is saved to the storage. Instead data stays in volatile memory and will be lost in case of software or hardware bug, crash or power loss.

For example you write text file and save it in text editor. But your text file not reach storage media right after that even if you force filesystem by call fsync. Filesystem flush you data **some later**.
You loss you file if something bad happened in between.

Databases also relies on proper fsync functioning in there durability.

And even hardware storage like hdd,ssd,raid controllers may lie to OS about successful writes due there own caching, firmware bugs or physical errors.

Also
https://superuser.com/questions/1389021/can-zfs-sync-disabled-cause-corruption-of-previously-written-data

https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html ( from 'Failure to sync' and below}

https://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html (9.2. Incomplete Disk Flushes)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-async-commit.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434872/writing-programs-to-cope-with-i-o-errors-causing-lost-writes-on-linux

Comment: The SQLite link you posted contradicts your answer: "the sync operation can be thought of as an I/O barrier. As long as all writes that occur before the sync are completed before any write that happens after the sync, no database corruption will occur. If sync is operating as an I/O barrier and not as a true sync, then a power failure or system crash might cause one or more previously committed transactions to roll back, but the database will at least continue to be consistent". Or does ZFS not preserve the order of writes?

Comment: About reordering https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T17417b2984f6c8ff

Comment: Also about reordering, specifically with `sync=disabled` https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T969c74e0a6dfdd74-M818821038c9248d92443f67a/qemu-guest-flushes-with-zfs-and-cachenone